# resource busy or locked, rename '...\node_modules\detect-port-alt\bin\detect-port.SOMENUMBER

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using CMD with administrator rights and cant install react-dev-utils.

The project is located on a network drive for which I have read and write rights.

EDIT: It seems everything works perfectly fine when not on a network drive...

I'd be interested in a fix anyway because it would be a tad bit more convenient to work on the network drive